# Invalid certificate popup associated with Outlook meeting reminder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, certificate

I have a meeting in Outlook (that I do not own, I am just an invitee), and every other week when it occurs I get this popup:

[image]

It comes up right after the reminder. Sometimes it pops up multiple times.

I have tried to "change the security settings" and it has no effect.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think this is more of an Outlook config and support question. Have you done what the error message said? What version of Outlook? What does your admin say (or is it a personal account)? I think you need a few more details here.

Comment: What do you mean by a "*legacy meeting*"? Have you tried deleting and recreating the meeting to see if it resolves the issue? What version of Outlook would be helpful?

Comment: @CharlieRB It's not my meeting.

Comment: In that case, you should change "*I have a legacy meeting*" to something that explains you do not own it.

Comment: This message means that Outlook is trying to send an email. Why would it send an email for a meeting that is not yours? In any case, if you are using a certificate that does not match your e-mail address, see this Microsoft article: [How to turn off e-mail matching for certificates in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/276597).

Comment: @harrymc I don't know, you tell me. This meeting recurs every two weeks and every two weeks the message pops up. It usually comes up right after the reminder if that means anything.

Comment: I cannot tell what Outlook is doing - it may be issuing an (encrypted??) confirmation message. Try the procedure in my link to see if this is indeed the problem. Take a backup (export) of the registry key first.

Comment: @TylerDurden Do you have outlook configured to sign/encrypt messages ? I think they have expired

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Yes, it is configured to automatically sign messages. What do you mean "they have expired"?

Comment: @TylerDurden If you go to certmgr.msc and check under personal section, do you have a certificate over there ? Is it still valid ?

Comment: I also had this very same issue and was only able to relsolve it by providing a certificate for that email address/account